# ROS Answers SE migration: KDL for arm

Tags: ros, kdl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to build a KDL representation of an arm. I am confused by what kind DH used. One kind is rotating z then rotating x axis. Another is rotating x then rotating z axis. My model is the latter. which one does the KDL library use?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9545/kdl-for-arm/) by [Nutan](https://answers.ros.org/users/170/nutan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2011-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are two different DH conventions, there is the original Denavit Hartenberg convention and the modified one published in Craig's Introduction to Robotics. KDL's chains are build up using Joints that can rotate about any axis, for DH you have to pick a rotation about the Z axis. For the offset between the current/previous and the next/current joint KDL uses plain homogeneous transformation matrices (Frame) since this is a lot more flexible, a Frame can easily be created from DH parameters, KDL supports both conventions, so if you want to build a chain using DH parameters you should do something like the following:

```
chain.addSegment(Segment(Joint(Joint::RotZ),Frame::DH(double a, double alpha, double d, double theta)));
```

or

```
chain.addSegment(Segment(Joint(Joint::RotZ),Frame::DH_Craig1989(double a, double alpha, double d,double theta)
```

-- Ruben

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Smits](https://answers.ros.org/users/350/ruben-smits/) with karma: 543 on 2011-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nutan](https://answers.ros.org/users/170/nutan/) on 2011-03-30**:
It is very useful. thanks, Ruben

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-04-26**:
Important: the initial row of the DH parameters should be added as a Joint::Fixed and not a Joint::RotZ.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Nutan,

As far as I can tell KDL does not directly support DH parameters to specify the kinematic chain. This is because this representation is quite limited (e.g. can't manage branching mechanisms).

I'd recommend you to use URDF, which is a XML based robot description file format which can be easily parsed into a KDL chain using kdl_parser.

You can find lots of information on both URDF and kdl_parser in the robot_model stack docs at http://www.ros.org/wiki/robot_model

---

Originally posted by [Miguel Prada](https://answers.ros.org/users/164/miguel-prada/) with karma: 1071 on 2011-03-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nutan](https://answers.ros.org/users/170/nutan/) on 2011-03-30**:
I will try kdl_parser. Thank you!